# Input lag tester

Tags: c++, c, openmp, latency

I have created a simple program that should be able to test for input latency.

What I mean by this is the delay between what your computer sends to the screen and when you press a key in relationship to it. This is for testing setups for online first-person shooter games.

The program works by flashing the console window black and white at a specific rhythm, and asking the user to press the spacebar or any other key to that rhythm. It uses getch to determine when the key was pressed, and runs the function that processes getch in parallel with the blinking console using OpenMP.

Is this usable as a basic, free input lag test, or what I should do to make it so if it's not?

```
//Fdisk's input lag tester
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

//My global variables. My functions run in parallel so it's easier to use global variables here.
    int i=0;
    long int outp[11];
    long int inpu[11];

//This function takes the input
int inputfunc() {
while(i<11) {
    getch();  //Takes the key input
    inpu[i]=clock(); //Marks the time the key was pressed
    if(inpu[i]-outp[i]>=0 && inpu[i]-outp[i]<5000) //Checks if result is valid
    i++; //Moves the program along so it doesn't blink for eternity
}
return 0;
}

//This function causes the screen to change color
int outputfunc() {
while(i<11) {
    system("color F0"); //Changes screen to white
    outp[i]=clock(); //Marks the time when screen became white
    usleep(400000); //Pause a bit here
    system("color 0F"); //Make the screen black again
    usleep(400000); //Pause again
}
return 0;
}
int main() {
    printf("Fdisk's Input Lag Tester\n\nPress any key when the screen flashes WHITE.     Let it flash a few times before pressing anything, so you can get used to the     rhythm. Using the spacebar is recommended. Be as precise as possible with what you     see on screen. A multicore or multithreading processor is required.\n");
    system("pause"); //Sorry my coding is bad
    system("cls"); //Again
 #pragma omp parallel sections //Parallel sections, these run in parallel on a dual core or dual threading machine
 {
     #pragma omp section
     {
         outputfunc(); //The output function, changes the screen's color
     }
     #pragma omp section
     {
         inputfunc();  //The input functions, waits for keypresses
     }
 }
 long int x;
 for(i=0;i<11;i++) {
x=x+(inpu[i]-outp[i]); //Difference between input and output=latency. This adds them up so we can take a mean value.
}
 x=x/11; //This takes the mean value
 x=x*(1000/CLOCKS_PER_SEC); //I think clock is always set to milliseconds but in case it's not
 printf("Your input latency: %ims\n",x); //Gives the input latency to the user
 system("pause"); //Pauses the program so it doesn't exit in case not running it from a command line
 usleep(10000000); //Prevents someone from mindlessly pressing space to exit
 system("pause"); //Another redundancy to prevent accidental quitting
 }
```

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com might be a better place for this kind of question.

Comment: Hey thanks I'll try posting it in there. Sorry I'm new to this.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code review and testing theory; it has been cross-posted to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/27994/simple-input-lag-test

Comment: This question was cross posted to code review, and is better answered there.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your test procedure isn't likely to provide even a rough estimate of the lag you're trying to measure.  It depends way too much on the user's input, whether he has any sense of rhythm, his hand-eye coordination, if he's had coffee, etc...  Also keep in mind that humans have a tough time distinguishing between two events which are less than ~30ms apart so that has an effect on the precision of your results.

I've had to perform a similar evaluation of a computer's lag in a different context but I believe the procedure I used can be adapted for your case.  I needed to measure the end-to-end delay of a system: digital camera ->image acquisition and processing hardware->windows application->display.  With the camera I filmed a camera flash.  I then used a 2nd camera (high speed) to film both the flash and its display on the monitor.  Going through the 2nd camera's video I could measure how many frames elapsed between the original flash and its display on the monitor.

In your case, you could take any camera and film both the keyboard and monitor, and save the video to file.  You can hit the keyboard and watch the result on the monitor.  Using any video editing software you can measure how many frames it took for the result to be visible.  Of course the precision depends on the frame rate of your camera, for example if you have a standard 30 fps camera then your measured lag will be a multiple of 33 ms.  If you need more precision you can always use a camera with higher frame rate.